# How to display the Error Message in Asp.Net Page using C#?

Tags: c#

I have a couple of dropdown boxex in my aspx page and i have search button also.

if the user clicks the "search" button without selecting any of the dropdown box, i want to display message like "Please select any Value"

My Page is created dynamically, all the controls are dynamically created. and i dont want to display the error message using any of the static aspx page controls like (Text Box, label or etc...)

and I want to display the error message from some other .cs file which i am referring in my aspx.cs file.

I have tried like the below: However it is not working.

```
if (first!= "-- Select The Item --" || second != "-- Select The Item --")
            {
                //Do Something
            }
            else
            {

                throw new Exception("Please select any Filter Type");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RequiredFieldValidator` Please check below SO link:

[How to add a RequiredFieldValidator to DropDownList control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280559/how-to-add-a-required-field-validator-to-dropdown-list-control)

Comment: i need like say for ex: string a = "hi" if(a !=""){//do} else {show some message in the page} but am checking these thing my one my common .cs file, not in aspx.cs file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dd1` and `dd2` are `DropDownList` control IDs, you could check the `SelectedIndex` property:

```
if (dd1.SelectedIndex != 0 || dd2.SelectedIndex != 0)
{
    //Do Something
}
else
{

    throw new Exception("Please select any Filter Type");
}
```

Comment: i need like say for ex: string a = "hi" if(a !=""){//do} else {show some message in the page} but am checking these thing my one my common .cs file, not in aspx.cs file

Answer (score 0):

Well javascript can be used to validate the drop down list....have a look at the link below
[How to validate dynamically created control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419769/how-to-validate-dynamically-created-control)